# What are the concerns of having Temp/variable tables inside a view?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

a friend of me is asking if i know any reasons why he should not included Temporal or variables tables inside a View in SQL-Server 2000. i could only think that a new table will be created everytime the view is accessed but i am wondering is there are any other concerns.

Thanks,

**EDIT:** This is not Possible

Comment: Do you have a working example to clarify?

Comment: you are rigth he could create he was having only the script since this was POC but when attempting to create it failed, thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Huh, can you even do that?

Server: Msg 4508, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 2
Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables. Table names that begin with '#' denote temporary tables.